# Razor form for input -- how to display a template for input?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

How do I create a template four user input? The requirement is to have an input text box display something line '0000-0000-00" to get a 10 digit number from a user that will be stored in the data base with out the '-'. This is for the aspnet core 3.1 Razor page.

Comment: Why can't you provide a standard text input? What is the relevance of the '-' if you plan to discard them? What exactly is the problem to be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view you add a placeholder to the input tag:

```
<input asp-for="MyProperty" placeholder="0000-0000-00"/>
```

You decorate the property MyProperty with an regex data annotation:

```
[RegularExpression("^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{1})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid input")]
public string MyProperty{ get; set; }
```

Comment: @WCS glad to hear. You can mark the answer as Accepted if my answer is the solution to your problem. This will also help other people.